# Calculation of dispersion energies for organometallic complexes with Gaussian

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, dispersion-correction

I've tried to calculate dispersion energies of some organometallic complexes with the  Gaussian software using `WB97XD/Gen` (`6-311+G**/LANL2DZ`) level of theory because I have Au as heavy metal.

The calculation doesn't even start and ends by link 301 error.

```
The job section # opt WB97XD/gen pseudo=read
```

And the output's last line was

```
R6DRO: No vdw radius available for IA=79
Error termination via lnk1e in /home/pctci/g09/l301.exe
```

My input file was perfectly drafted, I don't know what the problem is.
Anyone could help me please?

Comment: Please include the entire route and ideally more details on the job. Also check Gaussian documentation or search for l301 error (eg: https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/Gaussian_error_messages) which suggests this is an error in your input file. Also, this is more suited for Matter Modeling SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Van der Waal's radii for all atoms in the molecule are required to compute the dispersion for $\omega$B97X-D (this is also true for Grimme's dispersion). Unfortunately, Gaussian09 doesn't seem to have the radius for $\ce{Au}$ and it is also not possible to manually enter it through the input file. The radii for the elements up through $\ce{Rn}$ (atomic number 86) do seem to be available in Gaussian16 if that is an option.

Comment: Things are clear now, I'll apply your advice and I'll take your remarks into consideration.